# Use variable in static method inside nested function

Tags: php, global-variables

The title may be a bit confusing, so let me explain. I have a class and a method. That that method itself has a function. Like this:

```
class MyClass {
   public static function my_function($param) {
      function nested_function() {
        //do something with $param
      }
   }
}
```

So my question is, how can I access `$param` in `nested_function`?

**EDIT**

The reason I'm doing this is because of a wordpress thing. I need something like this:

```
class MyClass {
   public static function my_function($param) {
      function nested_function() {
        //do something with $param
      }

      add_action('init', 'nested_function');
   }
}
```

Comment: `function nested_function($param) use ($param) { // code here } `

Comment: @N.B. Does not work with **named** global functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a sensible thing to do. All named functions in PHP are global. Nesting them inside something else just makes their declaration conditional. I.e. you cannot call `nested_function` until you have called `MyClass::my_function`. And afterwards you cannot call `MyClass::my_function` again, because PHP will try to redeclare an existing function.

Maybe you want a closure, i.e. an *anonymous* function, which can include variables from the parent scope:

```
public static function my_function($param) {
    $nested_function = function () use ($param) {
        //do something with $param
    };
}
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you, the reason why I'm doing this is because I'm doing a wordpress thing. And I need to use the add_action. I will update my question.

Comment: That seems like a terrible convention Wordpress has there which does not allow objects or anonymous functions as callback. You can try if class methods work, e.g. `'MyClass::some_callback'`, then you can pass the variable through a class property. Otherwise it seems only `global` can help you (*shudder*).

Comment: Well the anonymous function did actually work! Thank you! One question though, from what php version is this going to work?

Comment: Anonymous functions where introduced in PHP 5.3.